# TFS query to get check in details

Tags: tfs

During check in there is a option for entering code reviewer name in TFS. What is the query for the code reviewer to retrieve checkin details that he\she has to review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the next release of Visual Studio we have removed this checkin note, since we have a very nice code review workflow built-in the product. You can view [Jamie Cool's session on \\BUILD\](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-811T) to see what is coming.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963) installed you can enter `tfpt searchcs` which will popup a "Search Changesets" window. 
There you can also filter by code reviewer.